# Android playing animations in a loop

Tags: java, android, android-animation

I'm trying to play animations on two `ImageViews` inside of a loop, where the Image of the ImageViews gets changed every loop, but as expected the user only sees the last image and animation.

Looking at the other posts I've tried things like `Thread.Sleep()` and `recreate()` at the end of the loop but no luck.

The purpose of the program is for a user to select 9 photos, and then does a rock-paper-scissors esque fight with computer images based on the RGB composition of the photos.

The program gets the photos for the ImageViews from two ArrayLists, `aiImages`, which is an ArrayList of strings of filenames in the drawable folder, and `Bitmaplist`, which is an ArrayList of `Bitmaps` that gets filled by photos the user selects from their own gallery.

The loop runs by setting the ImageViews

```
for(int x = 0; x < 9; x++) {

//Gets a bitmap from our PhotoActivity ArrayList and sets the player image view to be that bitmap
imageViewPlayerPhoto.setImageBitmap(PhotoActivity.bitmapList.get(x));

 
//Gets the resource ID of the computers photo
int computerImageResourceID = getResources().getIdentifier(aiImages.get(x), "drawable", 
            getApplicationContext().getApplicationInfo().packageName);

//Sets the computers image view to be the bitmap of the chosen computer photo
imageViewComputerPhoto.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromDrawable(computerImageResourceID));
```

Then doing some calculations with the photos chosen,

Then *attempts* to play the animation at the end of the loop,

```
imageViewPlayerPhoto.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.slide));

imageViewComputerPhoto.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.slide));

} //loop ends
```

Where `slide` is a simple xml animation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator">

    <translate android:fromXDelta="-500%" android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:duration="700"/>
</set>
```

The animations and setting the ImageViews work fine on the last iteration of the loop, but I just need help with displaying them every loop iteration and not just at the end

Edit:

As people suggested, I used an animation listener instead, and it works sort of well, except right now I'm having the issue where it will skip a photo during the animation, so it results with only 5 of the 9 images getting animated.

```
//reset the player image view to the first photo they chose
imageViewPlayerPhoto.setImageBitmap(PhotoActivity.bitmapList.get(0) );

//create an animation object from the animation resource folder
final Animation playerAnimation =AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.slide);

//explicitly invoke the animation one time
imageViewPlayerPhoto.startAnimation(playerAnimation);


//here is where we have to use some sort of logic to make the animation run x times

playerAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
@Override
public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

//sets the imageview at the start of the animation    
        imageViewPlayerPhoto.setImageBitmap(PhotoActivity.bitmapList.get(loopCounter) );
}

 @Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

//checks to see if another animation should happen
if(loopCounter < 8)
{
//sleeps the thread to allow a little pause in the UI
try
{
Thread.sleep(1000);
} catch (InterruptedException e)
{
  e.printStackTrace();
}

//increments the counter
loopCounter += 1;

//invokes the animation again
imageViewPlayerPhoto.startAnimation(playerAnimation);

}
else
 {
//if our counter is too high, cancel the animation
playerAnimation.cancel();
}
}

@Override
public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
}
});
```

Comment: you can't start (repeat) an animation inside loop, instead use a listener and on the method `onAnimationEnd()` restart your animation and change your images

Comment: don't do Thread.sleep(1000) to delay the start of an animation, use `playerAnimation.setStartOffset(1000)` property to do that